# What is the anatomical term for a two jointed leg?

Tags: zoology, terminology, biophysics, anatomy

Allow me to apologize in advance for the layman's terminology.

I'm wondering what the anatomical term for a cat- or a goat-style hind leg is.

Cats, goats, t-rexes, and many many other animals don't have human hind legs (i.e., with one knee / one pivot point). They have two pivot points, with one bone going down, then another going back-ish, then another going down again.

I've googled and googled for the answer, but I'm completely at a loss as to what this is called! *Is* there any name for that style of leg? I'm sure there's a lot of variation inside the category, but there *is* a category, correct?

Comment: ? cats have knees and hips as well... https://animalcorner.co.uk/cat-anatomy/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Welcome to Biology.SE!

I think you are talking about [plantigrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantigrade), [digitigrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitigrade) and [unguligrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungulate).

Please note that the number of joints in mammals does NOT vary, but only the relative length (and shape) of the different parts of the leg.

[image]

- A **Plantigrade** walks on the sole of the foot. 'Sole' translates to '*planta*' in Latin hence the name.

  - Examples: Human, squirrel, raccoons, ...
  - Below is a chimpanzee skeleton

[image]

- A **Digitigrade** walks on the digits (the toes).

  - Examples: dog, cat, hyena, ...
  - Below is a cat skeleton

[image]

- An **Unguligrade** walks on the nails. 'nail' translates to '*ungula*' in Latin hence the name.

  - Examples: cow, reindeer, goat, ...
  - Below is a cow skeleton

[image]

Comment: I think the final point you make (about the actual structure being invariant) is a major one and should be moved to the top so it isn't missed. The rest works well as an explanation of how that can be in spite their apparent dissimilarities.

Comment: I agree with you. I moved it on top. I thought the same when writing the answer but did not really know how to format. Hope that looks good enough. Feel free to edit to improve the format if you want. Thanks

Comment: I'd say that sentence placement, being immediately followed up with a side-by-side comparison chart, is perfect.

Comment: WOW I never noticed that they're all technically the same thing! That was more than helpful and extremely interesting! Thanks so much!

Comment: So amazing, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Birds are also confusing for a lot of people.

- Specifically, they assume that birds only have a two-jointed leg and therefore their knees "bend backwards."

[image]

However, like all [tetrapods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrapod), the leg structure and number of joints doesn't really change a whole lot:

[image: http://sunny.moorparkcollege.edu/~econnolly/amphibiantetras_files/image010.gif]

[image]

<sup>Copyright [Scott Hartman 2011](http://skeletaldrawing.blogspot.com/2011/09/um-hey-scientific-american-bird-knees.html)</sup>

The confusion is a result of the fact that -- similar to what @Remi.b points out in his [answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/51245/16866) -- birds are generally **digitigrade** animals. [see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_feet_and_legs)].

- In the case of the "backwards bending" bird knee: that's really the ankle joint.

  - The bird knee joint between the femur and [*tibiotarsus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibiotarsus) points forwards, but is hidden in feathers.
  - The bird ankle joint between the tibiotarsus and [*tarsometatarsus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarsometatarsus) points backwards.